# How do I convert s.st_dev to /sys/block/<name>

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to determine whether a file is on an HDD or an SDD.

I found out that I could check the type of drive using the `/sys/block` info:

```
prompt$ cat /sys/block/sdc/queue/rotational
1
```

This has `1` if it is rotational or *unknown*. It is `0` when the disk is an SSD.

Now I have a file and what to know whether it is on an HDD or an SDD. I can `stat()` the file to get the device number:

```
struct stat s;
stat(filename, &s);
// what do I do with s.st_dev now?
```

I'd like to convert `s.st_dev` to a drive name as I have in my `/sys/block` directory, in C.

What functions do I have to use to get that info? Or is it available in some `/proc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I really found it!

So my first solution, reading the partitions, wouldn't work. It would give me `sbc1` instead of `sbc`. I also found the `/proc/mounts` which includes some info about what's mounted where, but it would still not help me convert the value to `sbc`.

Instead, I found another solution, which is to look at the block devices and more specifically this softlink:

```
/sys/dev/block/<major>:<minor>
```

The `<major>` and `<minor>` numbers can be extracted using the functions of the same name in C (I use C++, but the basic functions are all in C):

```
#include <sys/types.h>

...

std::string dev_path("/sys/dev/block/");
dev_path += std::to_string(major(s.st_dev));
dev_path += ":";
dev_path += std::to_string(minor(s.st_dev));
```

That path is a soft link and I want to get the real path of the destination:

```
char device_path[PATH_MAX + 1];
if(realpath(dev_path.c_str(), device_path) == nullptr)
{
    return true;
}
```

From that real path, I then break up the path in segments and search for a directory with a sub-directory named `queue` and a file named `rotational`.

```
advgetopt::string_list_t segments;
advgetopt::split_string(device_path, segments, { "/" });
while(segments.size() > 3)
{
    std::string path("/"
                   + boost::algorithm::join(segments, "/")
                   + "/queue/rotational");
    std::ifstream in;
    in.open(path);
    if(in.is_open())
    {
        char line[32];
        in.getline(line, sizeof(line));
        return std::atoi(line) != 0;
    }
    segments.pop_back();
}
```

The `in.getline()` is what reads the `.../queue/rotational` file. If the value is not 0 then I consider that this is an HDD. If something fails, I also consider that the drive is an HDD drive. The only way my function returns false is if the `rotational` file exists and is set to `0`.

My function can be [found here](https://github.com/m2osw/snaplogger/blob/master/tools/shredlog.cpp#L690). The line number may change over time, search for `tool::is_hdd`.

---

### Old "Solution"

The file `/proc/partition` includes the major & minor device numbers, a size, and a name. So I just have to parse that one and return the name I need. Voilà.

```
$ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8       16 1953514584 sdb
   8       17     248832 sdb1
   8       18          1 sdb2
   8       21 1953263616 sdb5
   8        0 1953514584 sda
   8        1     248832 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5 1953263616 sda5
  11        0    1048575 sr0
   8       32  976764928 sdc
   8       33  976763904 sdc1
 252        0       4096 dm-0
 252        1 1936375808 dm-1
 252        2 1936375808 dm-2
 252        3 1936375808 dm-3
 252        4   16744448 dm-4
```

As you can see in this example, the first two lines represent the column names and an empty.The Name column is what I was looking for.

Comment: How would "these names" tell you if a file is stored on a HDD or SDD?

Comment: @alk, Sorry... my first find wouldn't work. It was not a good solution. I put the info for my new solution which actually works. I have a link to my new tool as well (actual code that compiles and runs).

Comment: The second  `dev_path += std::to_string(major(s.st_dev));` should use `minor` instead. Also, if you just read one number from a file, you can write `int value; in >> value;`

Comment: I guess the in >> value; would work in this case since I read just one value. Otherwise, I think it causes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1):

First of all for the input file we need to file on which partition the file exists
you can use the following command for that

```
 df -P <file name> | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Which will give you output something like this : /dev/sda3

Now you can apply following command to determine HDD , SDD

```
cat /sys/block/sdc/queue/rotational
```

You can use popen in your program to get output of these system commands

Comment: Hey, note that I want a C (C++) solution, not a set of Unix command lines. It's awful to have to parse the output of `df`! Also my main problem was: how do I go from `/dev/hda3` to `/dev/hda`. For a human, that's pretty easy, but I need my software to do it automatically.