# Find device file from the st_dev field in a file contained in the device

Tags: c, posix, stat, block-device

I want to access a device (opening it) with the only information about the device being an st_dev field in a file stat struct.

```
int fd;
char *path;
struct stat buf;
stat("/path/to/my/file", &buf);
// do some things with buf.st_dev
// then either path contains a path to the device refered by st_dev or fd contains a file descriptor refering to it.
```

I want to find a way to do this either in a POSIX portable way, or with distincts specific ways for at least Linux and MacOS systems

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this in POSIX. You may be able to do it using Linux-specific operations.

Comment: I am also keen to find a way to do in using Linux-specific operations

Comment: @Barmar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642729/how-do-i-convert-s-st-dev-to-sys-block-name is not a duplicate. Not only because it's for Linux, but also because it's only about locating a place with metadata about the device, not a place that allows reaching the content of the block device.

Comment: I assumed (incorrectly) that metadata would include the device path or mount info. @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct interaction with a block device requires a device node. The device node controls permissions (who can access the device directly).

Theoretical solution: call [`mknod` or `mknodat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mknod.html) to create a block device (`S_IFBLK`) with the given `dev_t` value. It needs to be on a filesystem that supports device files.

```
mknod("/var/run/myprogram/mydevice", S_IFBLK | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, buf.st_dev);
```

This requires elevated privileges: classically root permissions. On Linux, the `CAP_MKNOD` capability is sufficient, but some security frameworks may prevent even root from creating device nodes in random places. I don't know whether this requires more than root permissions on macOS.

Make sure not to give unprivileged programs access to the device.

Practical solution: look under `/dev` for a suitable device, i.e. a block device (`(found_stat.st_mode & S_IFBLK) != 0`) such that `found_stat.st_rdev == buf.st_dev`. There's no POSIX C function that does the recursive search, so you'll have to [code it manually](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Library:_POSIX).

While `find` can do the recursive traversal, it has no option to match a device file by its device number, which makes it inconvenient to locate the desired device.